# A definite integral that involves the incomplete Gamma function

Tags: integration

The question is to find the following definite integral:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}_{x,\beta}(\xi,\tau) := \int\limits_\xi^\tau  \Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot \eta^\beta \cdot e^{-\eta} d \eta 
\end{equation}
Now using integration by parts I have found the following recursion relations:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal I}_{x,\beta}(\xi,\tau) &=& -\left.\Gamma_x(\eta) \Gamma_{\beta+1}(\eta) \right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} - {\mathcal I}_{\beta+1,x-1}(\xi,\tau) \\
&=&\left.\Gamma_x(\eta) \frac{\eta^{\beta+1}}{\beta+1} e^{-\eta}\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} + \frac{1}{\beta+1} \frac{1}{2^{\beta+x+1}}\left.\Gamma_{\beta+x+1}(\eta)\right|_{\eta=2 \tau}^{\eta=2 \xi} + \frac{1}{\beta+1} {\mathcal I}_{x,\beta+1}(\xi,\tau)\\
&=&\left.\Gamma_x(\eta) \eta^\beta\cdot (-e^{-\eta})\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} + \frac{1}{2^{\beta+x}} \left. \Gamma_{\beta+x}(\eta) \right|_{\eta=2 \xi}^{\eta=2 \tau} + \beta {\mathcal I}_{x,\beta-1}(\xi,\tau)
\end{eqnarray}
If we iterate the last identity and assume that  $\beta$ is a positive integer the following identity holds:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}_{x,\beta}(\xi,\tau) = \left. \Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot(-e^{-\eta}) \cdot \left(\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\beta-1} \beta_{(p)} \eta^{\beta-p} \right) \right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} +
\left. \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\beta-1} \beta_{(p)} \frac{\Gamma_{\beta-p+x}(\eta)}{2^{\beta-p+x}} \right|_{\eta=2 \xi}^{\eta=2 \tau} + \beta! {\mathcal I}_{x,0}(\xi,\tau)
\end{equation} 
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}_{x,0}(\xi,\tau) := \left( - e^{-\eta} \Gamma_x(\eta) + 2^{-x} \Gamma_x(2 \eta) \right)_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau}
\end{equation}
If $\beta$ is a real number we can iterate the second identity from the top (in the list of recursion relations) and we get:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}_{x,\beta}(\xi,\tau) = \left.\Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot (e^{-\eta}) \cdot \left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^P \frac{\eta^{\beta+p}}{(\beta+1)^{(p)}}\right)\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} +
\left(\sum\limits_{p=1}^P \frac{1}{(\beta+1)^{(p)}} \frac{\Gamma_{\beta+p+x}(\eta)}{2^{\beta+p+x}}\right)_{\eta=2 \tau}^{\eta=2 \xi} +
\frac{1}{(\beta+1)^{(P)}} {\mathcal I}_{x,\beta+P}(\xi,\tau)
\end{equation}
for every $P \in {\mathbb N}_+$.  In the limit $P\rightarrow \infty$ the last term on the right hand side vanishes and we are getting a solution in terms of infinite series. Whereas the former series can be summed in closed form the later series involves an incomplete Gamma function with an increasing index and as such those series cannot be expressed in terms of functions that are implemented in software like Mathematica for example. My question is therefore is the integral above expressible in terms of elementary or some known special functions but not infinite sums of special functions. Is it possible to answer that question ?

Comment: Mathematica _can implement_ the incomplete Gamma function: `Gamma[x,eta]`.

Comment: If I iterate the second equation from the top I obtain series  of the kind $\sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\beta+1)^{(p)}} \cdot \Gamma_{\beta+p+x}(\eta) \cdot 2^{-\beta-p-x}$. This series of course can be evaluated with Mathematica , for example, and it does converge however the series itself is not a hypergeometric series, ie it does not belong to the class of special functions, at least according to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: In other words I want to know if the integral in question is expressible in terms of elementary functions, special functions but not infinite series of special functions. This is what I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with the last equation in the formulation of the question. We use the series expansion of the lower incomplete Gamma function and we take the limit $P \rightarrow \infty$. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&{\mathcal I}_{x,\beta}(\xi,\tau) = \left. \Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot \left(\Gamma(1+\beta) - \Gamma_{1+\beta}(\eta) \right)\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} + \\
&&\left.e^{-2 \eta} (2 \eta)^{\beta+x} \beta! 2^{-\beta-x} \sum\limits_{J=1}^\infty (2 \eta)^J \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^J \frac{(j+\beta+x-1)!2^{-j}}{(\beta+j)! (\beta+x+J)!} \right)
\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} \\
&&= \left. \Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot \left(\Gamma(1+\beta) - \Gamma_{1+\beta}(\eta) \right)\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} + \\
&& \frac{e^{-2 \eta } 2^{-x} \beta!}{\Gamma (\beta+x+1)} \left. \frac{\partial ^{x-1}}{\partial \alpha^{x-1}}
\left(\frac{e^{2 \eta } \alpha^{\beta+x} (-\gamma (\beta+x+1,2 \eta ))+e^{2 \alpha \eta } (\gamma (\beta+x+1,2 \alpha \eta
   ))}{\alpha-1}
\right)\right|_{\alpha=1/2} \\
&&=\left. \Gamma_x(\eta) \cdot \left(\Gamma(1+\beta) - \Gamma_{1+\beta}(\eta) \right)\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau} + \\
&&\frac{2^{-\beta-x} \, _2F_1(1,1-x;\beta+2;-1) \cdot \Gamma (\beta+x+1,2 \xi ,2 \tau )}{\beta+1}+\\
&&\frac{2^{-x} \beta!}{(\beta+x)!} e^{-2 \eta}\cdot 
\left.\left. {\mathcal  D}_\alpha^{x-1} \left( \frac{e^{2 \eta \alpha} \gamma(\beta+x+1,2 \eta \alpha)}{\alpha-1}\right) \right|_{\alpha=1/2}
\right|_{\eta=\xi}^{\eta=\tau}
\end{eqnarray} 
The second top equality is not really useful since calculating double sums is time consuming. However, using sister Celine's method we can very easily find a recurrence relation for the sum in question. Let us denote:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal F}_J := \sum\limits_{j=1}^J \frac{(j+\beta+x-1)!2^{-j}}{(\beta+j)! (\beta+x+J)!}
\end{equation}
then the following recurrence holds:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal F}_J - \frac{1}{\beta+x+J} {\mathcal F}_{J-1} = 
\frac{2^{-J}}{(\beta+x+J)(\beta+J)!}
\end{equation}
subject to ${\mathcal F}_0=0$.